# Can not find the right compiler for this cpp project using Jetbrains CLion

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clang

I want to compile an open source project but fail to compile the project. I am using Jetbrains CLion as my IDE.

**The project** (*feel free to clone and try yourself*): https://github.com/xetra11/vm

I have already tried the following compilers:

- LLVM/clang
- LLVM/clang++
- LLVM/clang-cpp
- LLVM/clang-cl
- MinGW64/g++
- MinGW64/gcc

All of them throw errors before really starting. Only two manage to compile but do so with compiling errors. The maintainer told me he was able to compile with clang and gcc. So I am very confused what I am doing wrong here.

**Using LLVM/clang-cpp**:

```
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/Entry.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/arraydata.cpp.obj
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/astnode.cpp.obj
In file included from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\Entry.cpp:1:
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src/netserver.h:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\arraydata.cpp:1:
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src/arraydata.h:2:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
         ^~~~~~~~
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/callstack.cpp.obj
1 error generated.
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\astnode.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
         ^~~~~~~~
make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\libsqfvm.dir\build.make:62: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/Entry.cpp.obj] Error 1
make.exe[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/callstack_apply.cpp.obj
make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\libsqfvm.dir\build.make:75: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/arraydata.cpp.obj] Error 1
make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\libsqfvm.dir\build.make:88: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/astnode.cpp.obj] Error 1
In file included from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\callstack.cpp:1:
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src/callstack.h:2:10: fatal error: 'memory' file not found
#include <memory>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\libsqfvm.dir\build.make:101: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/callstack.cpp.obj] Error 1
In file included from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\callstack_apply.cpp:1:
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src/callstack_apply.h:2:10: fatal error: 'memory' file not found
#include <memory>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\libsqfvm.dir\build.make:114: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/callstack_apply.cpp.obj] Error 1
make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:109: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/all] Error 2
make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:121: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/rule] Error 2
make.exe: *** [Makefile:130: libsqfvm] Error 2
```

**Using MinGW64/gcc**:

```
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/Entry.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/arraydata.cpp.obj
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/callstack_apply.cpp.obj
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/callstack_count.cpp.obj
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/callstack_exitwith.cpp.obj
[  8%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/callstack_for.cpp.obj
In file included from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\virtualmachine.h:11,
                 from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\arraydata.cpp:3:
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h: In member function 'void* dlops::resolve(std::__cxx11::string)':
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:65:11: error: invalid conversion from 'long long int (*)()' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
    return res;
           ^~~
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h: In member function 'bool dlops::try_resolve(std::__cxx11::string, void**)':
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:15:43: error: invalid conversion from 'FARPROC' {aka 'long long int (*)()'} to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
 #define DLOPS_LIB_SYM(H, N) GetProcAddress(H, N)
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:72:13: note: in expansion of macro 'DLOPS_LIB_SYM'
   *outptr = DLOPS_LIB_SYM(handle, name.c_str());
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\virtualmachine.h:11,
                 from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\callstack_count.cpp:2:
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h: In member function 'void* dlops::resolve(std::__cxx11::string)':
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:65:11: error: invalid conversion from 'long long int (*)()' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
    return res;
           ^~~
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h: In member function 'bool dlops::try_resolve(std::__cxx11::string, void**)':
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:15:43: error: invalid conversion from 'FARPROC' {aka 'long long int (*)()'} to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
 #define DLOPS_LIB_SYM(H, N) GetProcAddress(H, N)
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:72:13: note: in expansion of macro 'DLOPS_LIB_SYM'
   *outptr = DLOPS_LIB_SYM(handle, name.c_str());
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\virtualmachine.h:11,
                 from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\callstack_exitwith.cpp:2:
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h: In member function 'void* dlops::resolve(std::__cxx11::string)':
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:65:11: error: invalid conversion from 'long long int (*)()' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
    return res;
           ^~~
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h: In member function 'bool dlops::try_resolve(std::__cxx11::string, void**)':
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:15:43: error: invalid conversion from 'FARPROC' {aka 'long long int (*)()'} to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
 #define DLOPS_LIB_SYM(H, N) GetProcAddress(H, N)
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:72:13: note: in expansion of macro 'DLOPS_LIB_SYM'
   *outptr = DLOPS_LIB_SYM(handle, name.c_str());
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\virtualmachine.h:11,
                 from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\callstack_for.cpp:5:
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h: In member function 'void* dlops::resolve(std::__cxx11::string)':
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:65:11: error: invalid conversion from 'long long int (*)()' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
    return res;
           ^~~
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h: In member function 'bool dlops::try_resolve(std::__cxx11::string, void**)':
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:15:43: error: invalid conversion from 'FARPROC' {aka 'long long int (*)()'} to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
 #define DLOPS_LIB_SYM(H, N) GetProcAddress(H, N)
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:72:13: note: in expansion of macro 'DLOPS_LIB_SYM'
   *outptr = DLOPS_LIB_SYM(handle, name.c_str());
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\virtualmachine.h:11,
                 from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\callstack_apply.cpp:3:
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h: In member function 'void* dlops::resolve(std::__cxx11::string)':
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:65:11: error: invalid conversion from 'long long int (*)()' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
    return res;
           ^~~
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h: In member function 'bool dlops::try_resolve(std::__cxx11::string, void**)':
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:15:43: error: invalid conversion from 'FARPROC' {aka 'long long int (*)()'} to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
 #define DLOPS_LIB_SYM(H, N) GetProcAddress(H, N)
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:72:13: note: in expansion of macro 'DLOPS_LIB_SYM'
   *outptr = DLOPS_LIB_SYM(handle, name.c_str());
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\libsqfvm.dir\build.make:77: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/arraydata.cpp.obj] Error 1
make.exe[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\libsqfvm.dir\build.make:147: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/callstack_exitwith.cpp.obj] Error 1
make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\libsqfvm.dir\build.make:133: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/callstack_count.cpp.obj] Error 1
make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\libsqfvm.dir\build.make:161: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/callstack_for.cpp.obj] Error 1
make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\libsqfvm.dir\build.make:119: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/callstack_apply.cpp.obj] Error 1
In file included from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\virtualmachine.h:11,
                 from C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\Entry.cpp:2:
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h: In member function 'void* dlops::resolve(std::__cxx11::string)':
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:65:11: error: invalid conversion from 'long long int (*)()' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
    return res;
           ^~~
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h: In member function 'bool dlops::try_resolve(std::__cxx11::string, void**)':
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:15:43: error: invalid conversion from 'FARPROC' {aka 'long long int (*)()'} to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
 #define DLOPS_LIB_SYM(H, N) GetProcAddress(H, N)
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
C:\Development\Github\sqfvm\src\dlops.h:72:13: note: in expansion of macro 'DLOPS_LIB_SYM'
   *outptr = DLOPS_LIB_SYM(handle, name.c_str());
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\libsqfvm.dir\build.make:63: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/src/Entry.cpp.obj] Error 1
make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:109: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/all] Error 2
make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:121: CMakeFiles/libsqfvm.dir/rule] Error 2
make.exe: *** [Makefile:130: libsqfvm] Error 2
```

Comment: Yea I know VS but I want to stick to Jetbrains IDE. Thanks

Comment: clang is misconfigured since it doesn't find standard includes. gcc only complains about non standard pointer conversions which can be overcome using compiler option `-fpermissive` (or fixed code).

Comment: @xetra11 @Swordfish is correct. Do you have a C++ library installed? You can infuence where `clang` searches with `-isystem` and `-cxx-isystem`. Does `--print-search-dirs` print any directories that make sense?